# How to make a rest call to exrternal system while reading data from RTopic using Kafka Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The main requirement is to read data from the topic and send data to the external system over the rest API. There is also a requirement to send the message to the target system in the same order.

Example: Below two messages should be delivered to the target system in the same order (over rest API). If the first message is failed to send to the target system say 400 bad requests then 2nd message for the same customer (as mentioned below) should not be sent to the target system and both messages should be pushed to the Dead letter topic for later processing. All other records should be picked as usual.

First Message : Customer C1 -> Address_update -> Address 1
Second Message : Customer C1 -> Address_update -> Address 2

There are two problems here:

1. how to handle the failure scenario as 400 bad request
2. How to decouple REST call with Kafka stream otherwise throughput will be less as REST call might take 200 ms and retry mechanism as well.

Solution approach for problem 1 using state store:

1. Read the topic and check in the state store if the key is present in the state store.
2. If present then move the current record into DL topic and pick the next record.
3. If not present make an external rest call. In case an error occurred, add the record into the state store and push the current data into DL topic as well.
   So, here I am utilizing the state store to resolve the first problem.

Solution approach for problem 2 -> Can think of KTable but the issue is Ktable will always has the latest record not all records for the same customer. So all messages will not be delivered to the target system.

**How to resolve problem 2 or any better approach to resolve problem 1?**

Comment: spring integration?

Answer (score 0):

> how to handle the failure scenario as 400 bad request

Same as you would handle that in any HTTP client. This isn't a problem that Kafka addresses or handles for you.

> decouple REST call with Kafka stream

Not possible. You need to use some Kafka Consumer to poll records from the topic and deserialize the data before making any HTTP request.

You also said you want ordering, therefore, you cannot "decouple" the REST call via a background thread, for example. Otherwise, the consumer would continue reading later events. You need to block to preserve ordering, at least within the same Kafka partition. If you have multiple partitions that must be ordered with HTTP calls, then you need to repartition your topic...

You don't need Kafka Streams or a KTable here. In fact, **Kafka Connect** is more suited for this problem, unless you absolutely needed the HTTP response to forward to a new Kafka topic.